# Como puedo sumar un campo de los registros de un archivo directo?

Tags: array, c

Tengo que realizar la suma del campo de pro mejoras de cada registro de un archivo de acceso directo, con lo que tengo si me hace la suma pero solamente del primer registro y si tengo n registros intente reservarlo dinamicamente pero como mencione anteriormente sólo suma el primer registro:

```
void pro_mejoras(estudiante* pest, FILE* arc_estudiante)
{
    float total;
    int i = 0;
    int reg_cuenta;
    int cantidad;
    int numeroElementos;
    float* vector;
    char salir;
    fflush(stdin);
    rewind(arc_estudiante);

    if (!(arc_estudiante)) {
        printf("\n  Registro de estudiantes vac%co.\n\n", 161);
    }
    else {
        printf("total de la suma del comite pro-mejoras\n");

        while (!feof(arc_estudiante)) {
            reg_cuenta++;
            fread(pest, sizeof(estudiante), 1, arc_estudiante);

            vector = (float*)malloc(reg_cuenta * sizeof(float));
            if (vector == NULL) {
                printf("Problemas reservando memoria\n");
                exit(1);
            }
            vector[reg_cuenta] = pest->patronato;
            //fseek(arc_estudiante,-(sizeof(estudiante)),SEEK_END);
            total += vector[reg_cuenta];

            printf("\nel total de pro-mejoras es: %f\n", total);

            //printf("")
            free(vector);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```